# Using CSS to emulate <a target="_top">

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is it possible to alter a link behavior to target="_top" via CSS?

**Edit:**
Soon, my friends, soon. :)

```
a[target="_top"],
area[target="_top"],
form[target="_top"]
  { target: root }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: @Phil: Doesn't that use Javascript?

Comment: yes, but in light of the answer, I was providing an alternative

Comment: @Phil I don't know how `target="_top"` can be related to scrolling. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. CSS is for presentation.

**EDIT**: The [CSS3 Hyperlink Presentation Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/#the-target) talks about making this possible, but it is only a Working Draft and is not supported by any browsers.

Comment: Meh... Guess I'll have to use Javascript. :/

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth There seems to be no other choice. Why can't you simply add it to the HTML? If you explain it, I might be able to help.

Comment: The page is generated dynamically and I have no control over the way the links are generated. I can only alter the CSS of the page and I know the class of the parent divs of the link.

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth Go for Javascript then, there seems to be no other choice.

Comment: Check my edit to the first post. Seems like CSS3 will allow it.

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth Did not know that. Seems like no browsers support it yet. Edited my answer with this information.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could set a `class="top"` in your `a` tag, and then use javascript (via jQuery) to alter its behaviour:

```
$(function() {
  $('.top').attr('target','_top');
});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brRHP/3/

Comment: Yeah, that will be my path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, but add a `<div id="top"></div>` to the top of your body text.  Then have your anchor refer to index.php#top (if your page name is index.php)

Comment: Do you know what `target="_top"` does?